# Avoid Redirecting from html page when fields are empty

Tags: javascript, php

I have a registration form (`Register.html`) with `action="Register.php" onsubmit="return bc();"` where `bc()` is the name of validating function.

I have used javascript(`bc();`) in `Register.html` page for validation purpose. Even when the fields are incomplete `Register.html` gets redirected to `Register.php`.

How can stop this invalid redirecting

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `onsubmit="return bc();"` to `onsubmit="bc();"`
and in the

```
function bc(){
    //validation here
    return validated // true || false
}
```